# Injury - bruise -mainly on face

Tags: injury

I was playing football ,my nose has been hitted by ball and did it a red mark from hit.I didn't put ice immediately. I put ice after 1 hour but nothing happens. What to do now to make this bruise go away? Or reduce it.

Comment: You've had a question closed as off-topic before. I suggest you read the Help Center to understand which topics are on-topic.